# How do I model this relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm a bit new to rails so if this is very basic please bear with me.

I am creating something like a chat application. My model looks like this (from schema.rb)

```
create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "session_id"
end

create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "leader_id"
end
```

I've set up the basic relationship I want -- which is session_id is a foreign key in the people table as such:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :session
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :people
end
```

I want the leader_id to now be the person who is the "host" of the session (therefore its a foreign key to exactly one person). How do I setup an additional association so I can do:

```
session = Session.find_by_id(1)
host = Person.new(:name => 'joebob')
session.leader = host
```

Comment: you might want to rename your session, it is a reserved word for ror if i am not mistaken

Comment: Ahh good suggestion I will rename it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Rails that the leader_id is really a Person id by specifying the class name in the belongs_to association:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

Comment: Wow worked like a charm. Thanks!!! I guess belongs_to always means 'add a foreign key to this model'